# What's the difference between an *.ova file and a *.ovf file when exporting from VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, export, file-extension

I'm trying to export a Virtual Machine I have on VirtualBox so I can back it up, and when I went to export it, I was prompted with a "Save As..." dialog that asks me if I want to save it as a .ovf or an .ova file.

What is the difference between these two formats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As specified in the [VirtualBox Manual: 1.13. Importing and Exporting Virtual Machines](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf):

> Appliances in OVF format can appear in two variants:
>
> 1. They can come in several files, as one or several disk images, typically in the widely-used VMDK format (see the section called “Disk image files (VDI, VMDK, VHD, HDD)”) and a textual description file in an XML dialect with an .ovf extension. These files must then reside in the same directory for VirtualBox to be able to import them.
> 2. Alternatively, the above files can be packed together into a single archive file, typically with an .ova extension. (Such archive files use a variant of the TAR archive format and can therefore be unpacked outside of VirtualBox with any utility that can unpack standard TAR files.)

So, picking `.ovf` will export a bunch of files into a single folder.  Picking `.ova` will package all those items that would end up in the `.ovf` folder into a single (often rather large) file.  Which you'd rather have is up to you.